# child dies before TIMEOUT in pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I am using pexpect in a python code to run a system command. On running the command, the user may or maynot be prompted with a question. if prompted he must answer y. I want this to happen automatically. I have written the following code -

```
child = pexpect.spawn( "module load xyz" )
child.expect( "Are you sure you want to clear all loaded modules.*" )
child.sendline( "y" )
```

My question is what will happen if the system does not prompt the user with the question and the child dies after successful execution of the command?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: There are three possibilities for what would happen given his code.  1) it would hang, waiting for that text to appear followed by a newline.  2) it would raise an `EOF` error if the requested string was not found in the output.  3) it would hang because no it is waiting for either a newline character for for the buffer to fill up.  pexpect can be finicky.

Comment: Couldn't try it yet as there is some issue in the module command.. Will try with some other command wand let you know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `expect` statement in a `while` to continue looping and a try/except to handle the situation where the expected return value is not found.  This will allow you to gracefully determine that you have hit the end of the process' output while, at the same time, acting upon the warning message if required.

```
child = pexpect.spawn( "module load xyz" )
while child.isalive():
    try:
        child.expect( ""Are you sure you want to clear all loaded modules.*" )
        child.sendline( "y" )
    except EOF:
        pass
```

To do this, you will need to call `from pexpect import EOF`.

One more note, though.  This will hang unless you either set your buffer to an appropriate size (something I've never gotten the hang of with pexpect) or the string you are expecting is followed by a newline.  If neither of these is true, you will hang and have no idea why.  In all honesty, I prefer to just do it the hard way and use `subprocess.Popen`, then read from `stdout` and `stderr` and write to `stdin`.

One more comment.  Be careful about using wildcards.  They tend to behave in odd ways.  Given what you are looking for, you should be able to just drop the asterisk from your expected string.

Answer (score 1):

To run the command and to answer `'y'` if the question is asked using `pexpect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

pexpect.run("module load xyz", events={
    "Are you sure you want to clear all loaded modules": "y" + os.linesep
})
```

If you want to use `pexpect.spawn` directly then the simplified version could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("module load xyz")
while True:
    i = child.expect(["Are you sure you want to clear all loaded modules",
                      pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
    if i == 0:
        child.sendline('y')
    else: # child exited or the timeout happened
        break
```